# How to use Union Inner Join Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that a previous employee created and is working correctly. However, I need to add a table to it called 'info' and am having a hard time with it. The 'info' table has a user column that should match the user_id column in the users table.

The info table has columns such as user (which is the user id), company, phone, fullname. The query currently emails out a to users that are registered to a specific tender. Then a log file is created and in that log file I need to display information from the info table such as company, phone, and fullname.

I've tried adding it after the first INNER JOIN like this:

```
INNER JOIN info
 ON info.user = users.user_id
```

The query will run but it won't grab any info from the info table when I try to display it.

Below is the query that works:

```
$sql = '
        SELECT users.user_id
             , users.username
          FROM users
        INNER
          JOIN registrations
            ON registrations.user = users.user_id
           AND registrations.tender = '.mysql_real_escape_string($tender).'

        UNION 
        SELECT users.user_id
             , users.username
          FROM users

        INNER
          JOIN user_divisions
            ON user_divisions.user = users.user_id

        INNER
          JOIN tender_divisions
            ON tender_divisions.division = user_divisions.division    
           AND tender_divisions.tender = '.mysql_real_escape_string($tender).'

        WHERE
            users.verified = 1 
        GROUP 
            BY users.user_id
        ';
```

Comment: You should add details about your info table and show what you have tried

Comment: @thomasG - just updated it now.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `SELECT users.user_id, users.username` is all it does (select), no matter how much tables you join. Add the proper select-fields to get more detailed results.

Answer (score 0):

Usent the same format
Make sure that all user are exist in users table to show all the info data
SELECT users.user_id
             , users.username
          FROM info
        INNER
          JOIN users
            ON info.user =users.user_I'd

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input, this should work (I have formatted the SQL to match my style)

```
        SELECT users.user_id, users.username, info.*
        FROM users
          INNER JOIN registrations ON  registrations.user = users.user_id
                                   AND registrations.tender = '.mysql_real_escape_string($tender).'
          INNER JOIN info ON info.user = users.user_id    

    UNION 

        SELECT users.user_id , users.username, info.*
        FROM users
          INNER JOIN user_divisions ON user_divisions.user = users.user_id
          INNER JOIN tender_divisions ON  tender_divisions.division = user_divisions.division    
                                      AND tender_divisions.tender = '.mysql_real_escape_string($tender).'
          INNER JOIN info ON info.user = users.user_id            
        WHERE users.verified = 1 
        GROUP BY users.user_id
```

There's no reason for it to not work if the initial query is working fine.

If it doesn't return any record, it means that you don't have a match between your user table and your info table. You can change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` to verify this.

---

Remark:

I don't like the `GROUP BY` in the last query. It works with MySQL but this is not ANSI standard, and you might get into issues if your move to another DB with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode activated

You should have the same columns in the `SELECT` than in the `GROUP BY`. If the aim is to remove duplicates (it looks like as you don't use an aggregate function in the `SELECT`) then you should use `DISTINCT` instead

Worth a read : [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: thanks for your help! I had to take out info.* because it's not a column in the users table. However, it didn't work. It's strange because I have a user id called 'user' in the info table which is 600. I have the same user id in the users table 'user_id' as well. It should match up.

Comment: `info.*` means _all columns from info table_. You should debug this : 1. Run the 2 queries separately and observe the results. 2. Change the joins from INNER to LEFT and check again. With `SELECT *`, display all columns to figure out what is empty. I can't say more